# Exchange server sends email even when bad credentials supplied

Tags: email, exchange

From a PC on our domain, our Excahnge server allows me to send email without providing username/password credentials using a program I wrote in C#.

More interestingly, if I supply *bad* credentials e.g. my username and a bad password, it still succeeds.

Is this a feature of Exchange, that if it decides I have permission to send emails without providing credentials, it doesn't even bother checking?

I don't suppose there's any kind of flow-chart which describes the logic used when deciding if I have permission to send the given email? There must be quite a few permutations!

Answer (score 1):

You can make exchange ignore creds by creating an anonymous connector, meaning that emails coming from certain IP addresses and ports no authentication will be needed.

If you have access to the exchange console, you can see (and create) those under "Server Configuration > Hub Transport > Receive Connectors tab".

Comment: Sounds like this must be the case; I'm a programmer not a sysadmin but this would make sense - it doesn't even _look_ at the credentials.